# Python - Using variables between functions

Tags: python

Having some trouble getting this to work... Basically I want to use the var binary (returned from inputF) in the convert function. I returned the variable, passed it in, and defined it... Stuck on what to do :/ I also defined it in main and passed it into the function... Says: Local variable 'binary' referenced before assignment.

```
def inputF():
  binary = input("Enter bin #: ")
  return(binary)

def convert(binary):
  binary = inputF(binary)
  print(binary)
  return

def main():
  binary = input(binary)
  inputF()
  convert(binary)
  return
main()
```

Comment: There's also a problem in `convert()`, the function `inputF()` does not take a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming in `main` because of the `input(binary)` statement (the error message should have included a line number pointing at that). If you want `main` to coordinate the `inputF` and `convert` functions, you can do:

```
def main():
    binary = inputF()
    convert(binary)
```

Then `convert` should just do whatever conversion it needs to do. Since you pass `binary` as an argument, you don't need to call `inputF` there:

```
def convert(binary):
    print(binary)
    # Do whatever you need to do
```

That way, `convert` doesn't need to worry about input at at all, and just processes the data passed to it as the argument.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'binary' referenced before assignment

This is because you are passing the variable `binary` before it's created.

```
something = input(binary)
```

What is the value of `binary`?  (there isn't one).

How about:

```
binary = input("Enter value for 'binary'> ")
```